# Getting current UIViewController using Swift on a Phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm very new into iOS app development and I'm thinking of using Swift on a Cordova application.

I'm currently writing a plugin that requires current UIViewController so as to use UIAlertController.

Since a view controller is required to show UIAlertController instance, how do I get it in case of a Cordova application? Or do I have to create a new instance of UIViewController?

This is the piece of code I'm using:

```
import Foundation

@objc(ActionSheet) class ActionSheet : CDVPlugin {
  func show(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
    var message = command.arguments[0] as String

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hey AppCoda", message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    // Where to get viewController?

    viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as I know, swift plugins aren't supported yet. Anyway, on objective-c plugins you can get the viewController with self.viewController, not sure how to do it in swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDVPlugin has a viewController property, so your ActionSheet class has access to it. Your code works fine as is for me. This is what I see when I run it and call the show method from js.

[image]

Are you having any issues?

Comment: Can you explain how you accessed viewController reference from CDVPlugin? Sorry if it's a dumb question. Total noob with iOS development here. A piece of code will help.

Comment: Anything that inherits from CDVPlugin has a reference `viewController` or `self.viewController`

Comment: Awesome! That was too easy than I expected.